# Run script on change in nodemon

Tags: node.js, package.json, nodemon

Is it possible to run a script on change using nodemon?

Is it possible to do something like this: `nodemon --watch src --exec yarn run my-script`?

So, ideally I'd like to run a script only when there're changes in a `src` folder

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As indicated [in the Nodemon docs](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#triggering-events-when-nodemon-state-changes) you can add a restart event command in `nodemon.json`:

```
{
  "events": {
    "restart": "yarn my-script"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 36):

Just put quotes around your script that you want to execute:

```sh
nodemon --watch src --exec "yarn run my-script"
```