# nodemon | how configurate to ran different script

Tags: node.js, config, nodemon

How i can configurate nodemon config to:

- if .ts files change - reload with "npm start"
- if .graphql file change - reload with "npm run type-gen && npm run start"

EDITED

I`am just run 2 nodemon with different configs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51225642/11563561 , You might find this useful, basically, you create a config and put things according to your requirements.